# Aggregate the values by Country return the output as csv file

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to aggregate the values by country but failed to get the required output!!!
[link of **input_data** and required **Output_data**](https://github.com/1576dkm/Spark-Data)

Here is my code in scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import shapeless._0
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext



object Assignment {
  val COMMA = ",".r
  val SEMICOLON = ";".r
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={

    val sc=SparkSession.builder()
     .appName("Aggregate values by country!!!")
     .master("local")
     .getOrCreate().sparkContext

     val rdd=sc.textFile("data.csv")
     val header=rdd.first
     val rdd1=rdd.filter(_!=header)
     val tRdd= rdd1.map(x=>{val data= COMMA.split(x); (data(0)->data(1))}) 
     val gRdd=tRdd.groupByKey()
     val ans=gRdd.map(x=> (x._1->func1(x._2.toArray[String])))
     val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
     import sqlContext.implicits._
     val df=ans.toDF((COMMA.split(header).toSeq): _*)
     df.write.csv("TransformedData")


  }
```

Funtion to aggregate the values by country:

```
def func1(ref: Array[String]):Array[Long]=
  {
   val ref2=ref.map(x=>SEMICOLON.split(x).map(y=>y.trim.toLong))
   val ref3=ref2.transpose
   ref3.map(x=>x.sum) 
  }
}
```

**I think my solution is not correct!!!**

Comment: can you describe how you want to aggregate your data and show your current (wrong) output?

Comment: @moe aggregate the data by country but the values are aggregated according to the index of the values like look in input data the values of country india ,the first output value of india is the sum of first values of india of the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code :

```
val resultRDD = rdd1.map{r =>
    val Array(country, values) = r.split(",")
    country -> values
  }.reduceByKey((a,b) => a.split(";").zip(b.split(";")).map{case (i1,i2) => i1.toInt + i2.toInt}.mkString(";"))
```

Here rdd1 is the one you were using

Output (pairRDD) :

```
(China,218;239;234;209;75)
(Canada,183;258;150;263;71)
(Germany,144;166;151;172;70)
(India,246;153;148;100;90)
(England,178;114;175;173;153)
```

Edit : 
You can create a case class to store your Data. ie:

```
case class CountryAgg(country: String, values:String)
import spark.implicits._

val myDataset = resultRDD.map{case (country:String, values:String) => CountryAgg(country, values)}.toDS
```

Then you can save your dataset into some CSV File

Comment: OK, so create a Case class to store your data in it (will edit my answer)

Comment: please tell me how to add header(Country,Values) ??? @baitmbarek

Comment: you can use your Dataset to write csv files. Your DataFrameWriter enables you to specify options, like option("header","true") to automatically add a header to each generated CSV file. Note that you should also specify the '.format("csv")' method with a save action (or use the 'csv' method without specifying the format instead of save) in order to save CSV files.